# Is there any website/service that notifies you when a site has changed?

Tags: notification

Is there any website that offers a service that notifies you by email when a given site changes? I want to track changes on the site http://www.thief4.com.

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [changedetection.com](http://www.changedetection.com/).

It's no frills, but it monitors web pages and sends you email updates when a page changes (and you can define what sort of changes you want to monitor).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one that I've used, it sends you an email each day of changes to a particular page or set of pages you want to watch: `http://www.watchthatpage.com/`.

Answer (score -1):

I use [Content Site Monitor](http://www.contentsitemonitor.com) to notify me when the website changes.